# What is this arrangment of elements in broadcast news called?

Tags: style-identification, terminology

I am searching for the name of an arrangement typically used in news-broadcast designs, exemplified below (Terror in Boston, with rectangle above). In French we call these *mortaise,* but I cannot find the English term for it.

[image]

Comment: My question got edited but this kind of graphics has a name in the broadcast field, just like you could say something is a "header" or a "folio" or a "table of contents". I am not looking for a style name.

Comment: You may have better luck with this question at http://video.stackexchange.com -- where the video folks hang out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a naming convention for Television News Graphical Layout might exist, the names for those kind of graphical elements may vary from place to place in the world depending on how a certain culture/business field prefer to reference/call those. Anyway, the one in the image you provided I believed it's called **"Over the Shoulder"**, see this [paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/237075281_A_Television_News_Graphical_Layout_Analysis_Method_Using_Eye_Tracking) for more details.

> The graphic element **"Over the Shoulder"**, normally appears in the
>   news that has higher impact, therefore revealing the relevance of the
>   news story. The term "Over the Shoulders" is applied because it
>   generally appears in the superior part of the shoulder of the anchor.
>   The "Over the Shoulders" is usually accompanied with an image or icon,
>   with the intention of establishing a link with the news story being
>   presented.

[source](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/237075281_A_Television_News_Graphical_Layout_Analysis_Method_Using_Eye_Tracking)

Many of these elements are sold as ready made video packs, most of the time as editable After Effects projects on marketplaces such as [videohive.net](http://videohive.net/item/ultimate-broadcast-news-pack/5869789) which usually include elements such as **Openers**, **Bugs**, **Lower Thirds**, **Split Screens**, **Text Tickers**, **Over the Shoulders**, **Info Screens**, **Bumpers**, and many others.

I hope it helps.

Comment: "Over the shoulder" is not apropiate term, becouse it is a ciematograpy one used to see a part of the interlocutor when you are photographing the main actor.

Comment: I agree with you in part. However, it doesn't mean it couldn't be used to describe this specific graphical element too. I've just enhanced the answer details, and I'm researching now for more references. Indeed it seems to be a common name so far used by the News TV Channels worldwide. A simple google search should return some valid results https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Television+News+graphics+over+the+shoulder&es_sm=119&biw=1920&bih=934&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMItNeshJquyAIVCwuQCh2uVADH

Comment: Additional reading resource here: https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Zg2PAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA101&ots=ktcFEAoIhS&dq=Television%20News%20graphics%20over%20the%20shoulder&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA100#v=onepage&q=Television%20News%20graphics%20over%20the%20shoulder&f=false

Comment: Interesting....

Comment: It is probably called an "over-the-shoulder b-roll insert"

Comment: Actually I checked with a client and this is how they call it, even if it seems misguided. As for the b-roll insert part, it depends. Some news channel insert b-roll there and some have graphic designers doing static designs.

Answer (score 2):

As a professional video editor working in broadcast, and as a college-educated broadcast journalist, this graphic is indeed called an "over-the-shoulder" (or OTS, for short).